# Deleting a file from Single User mode

Tags: macos, terminal

My macbook's hard disk has 10 MB free space and the login is not possible.

I booted to Single User mode to delete some files but the paths were totally different than the paths I get when I just click on Terminal app from /Applications/Utilities. For instance I've got 'var' and 'root'.

All I need to do is to access the Applications folder through the command line and then to delete some apps.

Can you tell me how can I access the Applications folder?

Comment: thanks very much but when i try cd /Applications, i can only see safari.app and utilities. i also get a message saying it is "read only"

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /Applications
ls -latrsq (shows all files, including their sizes)
rm -rf Application.app
```

If the application name contains spaces, use a \ in each space.  Example, Microsoft Word 2011.app would be Microsoft\ Word\ 2011.app

Comment: thanks but it didnt worked. can you please read my comment to grgarside and answer again?

Comment: Thanks, but was a downvote truly necessary?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the OS X installer volume.

> cd /Volumes
> cd *volume name of your hard disk*
> cd Applications
> ls -latrsq (shows all files, including their sizes)
> rm -rf Application.app

Comment: now we are on to something :) a + from me

Comment: [general note] votes are anonymous. We'll never know whose it was (not mine, btw)

Comment: thank you.
i do cd/Volumes then: ls
what i get is: .Trashes and OS X Base System..
what shall i do then?

Comment: It sounds like it doesn't see your boot volume.  Have you tried booting into recovery mode?  Does it show up in Disk Utility?

Comment: i've booted from recovery mode :) 
of course i havent gave a negative vote to anyone!

Comment: If you are booted into the recovery/setup environment, do you see the option Disk Utility under the Utilities menu?  If your boot drive doesn't show up under /Volumes in Terminal, I'm curious if it shows up in Disk Util

Comment: yes i can see the HDD listed on disk utility and i also see the
disk 1 (OS X Base System)

Comment: OS X Base System is the install media

Comment: Why don't you try performing a fresh installation of OS X and selectively restore some of your content from your latest Time Machine backup?

Comment: i dont have a time machine. i think the best to do now is to take off the hdd, mount it to another mac as an external drive and remove some files.

if you have a better idea, please let me know, if now, it is ok, you helped a lot and i am thankful!

unfortunately i cant vote your answers cause i have a very low reputation. (it says i need at least 14.)

Comment: Spend the friggin money on a hard drive, and start backing up your stuff!!!!  There are no excuses for losing a file, none.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /Applications
```

This opens the /Applications folder at root. There's no need to use relative paths.